# What are the Reserved Keywords in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I've walked through https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference but I could not find reserved keyword, used in Kotlin. How many keywords does Kotlin have?
As long as we know Java has its own keyword list like here: [image]

Comment: After all this time, there's still no definitive simple list of "character strings you should not use" for kotlin.  Sheesh!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPD:** The keyword reference was added to the Kotlin docs: [(here)](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html)

---

An auto-generated list of *hard* keywords for the current version can be found in Kotlin Github repo: [(here)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/descriptors/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/renderer/KeywordStringsGenerated.java)

There are more soft keywords, which behave like keywords in certain context, like `it`, `field`, `object`, access & member modifiers.

More about context in which soft keywords are treated as keywords can be found in the [grammar reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html), along with the whole grammar, including hard keywords in their places.

Comment: what is the difference between a keyword and a soft keyword?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf A soft keyword is treated as a keyword only in certain context, and not anywhere else. For example, you can declare a `val override = 1`, but `override ` is also treated as a a keyword when it is in front of `fun` in a function declaration.

Comment: Thus you should NEVER use a "soft" keyword as an identifier because it's easy to change the context as code gets modified over time and people tend to forget these minute details.  Aaannnd therefore there's really no such thing as a "soft" keyword--they are just keywords.  And there's a LOT of 'em.

Comment: Link to kotlin github repo is broken, tried to find it but file no longer exists, now it's this: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/core/descriptors/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/renderer

Answer (score 5):

There is a grammar reference https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html

So anything in double quotes is a keyword (like `"class"`) or an operator (like `"%"`). However many keywords are "soft" (like `"file"`), meaning that they depend on their syntactic position and still may be used as function names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Quick def: Reserved words in programming languages (sometimes called keywords) are character strings that have special and specific uses only.  Compilers use these words as landmarks when parsing code.  Programmers should not name variables, functions, nor classes using these words.  Of course, using them in comments is perfectly fine.

There are **LOTS** of keywords in Kotlin.  But there's no definitive number because:

1. The definition of keywords (reserved words) in Kotlin is poorly
   defined.
2. Kotlin is so new, the number of keywords keeps changing (and not getting smaller!).

The "official" keywords are generally divided up into categories: hard, soft, and operators.  Soft keywords are character strings that may be a keyword, depending on the context.  Any programmer with any experience will never take the risk of using a soft keyword for obvious reasons.  So at the time the number of keywords in Kotlin are

31 (hard) + 48 (soft) + 41 (operators) = some number too big to keep track of

Yup, that's 120 keywords.  Or 79 if you don't count operators.  By comparison, K&R's C language has 28 keywords with 22 operators = 50.  And that's good enough to write Unix.

And we haven't even started talking about *Annotations* (the sly way of slipping in lots and lots of keywords without really having to officially declare them)!  Like Kotlin's parent, Java, Kotlin uses Annotations liberally, and there is no limit to the number of them--you can even make your own!

That said, a list of "required" annotations should be included as part of Kotlin's reserved words, but I'm feeling lazy.  Let's just say that there are about two dozen.  This brings our total of reserved words to... 144 (waaaaay more than I can keep track of).  Thanks kotlin, for simplifying my life!